# Showing view from onPause of an android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to show one of my view when onPause is called from an Android activity.
Would it be a good practice to do? Is there any issues if I show it from the onPause?

This view will be shown as a background when my activity is partially visible.

Comment: `onPause()` is called when Activity is going to background. Don't you think you won't even see the view if you show it in this method. Also, it might lead to various errors/issues.

Comment: I want to cater for the cases where my activity is partially visible. I want to display a different background when my activity is paused but is partially visible

Answer (score 2):

**Basically it is not good practice to do so.**

The Activity is still slightly visible ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)), but the user may not even notice if you change anything.

Also everything in `onPause` should be fast.

The documentation says:

> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.

So it will slow down the start of the next `Activity`, also the `Activity` animation might be a little laggy if you are updating the UI in `onPause()`

---

You may use onResume() to show your view.